# Entity Framework Core - (Kind of subquery)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity

I use fluent API and Ef Core.

This is my linq:

```
 var data = (from candidateHP in _cempContexto.CandidateHiringProcessSummary
              join jobsHP in _cempContexto.JobHiringProcessSummary on candidateHP.JobCode equals jobsHP.JobCode
              join job in _cempContexto.Vaga on jobsHP.JobCode equals job.Codigo
              join candidateJob in _cempContexto.TrCandidatoVaga on new { X = job.Codigo, Y = candidateCode } equals new { X = candidateJob.VagaCodigo, Y = candidateJob.CandidatoCodigo }
              where
              candidateHP.CandidateCode == candidateCode
              select
              new
              {
                JobCode = jobsHP.JobCode,
                CompanyCode = job.EmpresaCodigo,
                Title = job.Titulo,
                HasImage = true,
                CompanyName = job.NomeEmpresa,
                QuantityJobs = job.QuantidadeVaga,
                Location = job.CidadeCodigo,
                QuantityResumeSent = jobsHP.QuantityResumeSent,
                JobStatusCode = jobsHP.StatusCode,
                CandidateStatusCode = candidateHP.StatusCode,
                StatusCode = job.StatusCodigo,
                ResumeSentDate = candidateJob.Data,
                InsertDate = job.DataDeCadastro,
                EndDate = job.DataDeSaida,
                city= _cempContexto.TrVagaCidade.SelectMany(p => _cempContexto.TrVagaCidade.Where(q => q.VagaCodigo == candidateHP.JobCode).Select(q => new { q })).ToList()
              })
              .ToList();
```

I need to Fill city with that subquery. I need a better way to do that, How could I proceed?

Comment: Step 1 is to get rid of that horrific anonymous type and turn it into a class.

Comment: Why are there no Navigation Properties in your model?  All your queries would be vastly simpler if you had them.

Comment: What is the extra `.Select` for at the end?

Comment: @stybl I've changed anonymous to a class :)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft -> I tried to use navigation properties, but, ef core turned my navigations properties in a big query and bring much unnecessary data :(

Comment: @NetMage Sorry for that, it is my prototype.

Comment: Navigation properties only change the query if you use them in the query, or request eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

Split code into two queries :

```
var query = (from candidateHP in _cempContexto.CandidateHiringProcessSummary
              join jobsHP in _cempContexto.JobHiringProcessSummary on candidateHP.JobCode equals jobsHP.JobCode
              join job in _cempContexto.Vaga on jobsHP.JobCode equals job.Codigo
              join candidateJob in _cempContexto.TrCandidatoVaga on new { X = job.Codigo, Y = candidateCode } equals new { X = candidateJob.VagaCodigo, Y = candidateJob.CandidatoCodigo }
              where
              candidateHP.CandidateCode == candidateCode
              select
              new
              { jobsHP = jobsHP, job = job, candidateJob = candidateJob}).ToList();

var data = query.Select(x => new {
                JobCode = x.jobsHP.JobCode,
                CompanyCode = x.job.EmpresaCodigo,
                Title = x.job.Titulo,
                HasImage = true,
                CompanyName = x.job.NomeEmpresa,
                QuantityJobs = x.job.QuantidadeVaga,
                Location = x.job.CidadeCodigo,
                QuantityResumeSent = x.jobsHP.QuantityResumeSent,
                JobStatusCode = x.jobsHP.StatusCode,
                CandidateStatusCode = x.candidateHP.StatusCode,
                StatusCode = x.job.StatusCodigo,
                ResumeSentDate = x.candidateJob.Data,
                InsertDate = x.job.DataDeCadastro,
                EndDate = x.job.DataDeSaida,
                city= query.Select(y => y.candidateHP.JobCode).Select(q => new { q })).ToList()
              })
              .ToList();
```

Comment: --> I did that in a different way: I put in a for-each, and the result is similar yours. The ef open and close connection for each in a list.

Comment: Did it work?  I giving an example of splitting query to get your desired results.  If you implemented the code a little different great.

Comment: @jdeweng --> Yep, your code is ok, but not awesome, I imagine that I got this result in just one query, because of your way open and close connection for each row in a list of content.

Comment: It is not obvious in the code where the connection opens and closes.